# Shoot projectile at exact angle

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a simple shooting mechanism which instantiates a 'shot' based on the angle of rotation of the shooter. My problem here is even though the shooter is oriented at 0*, the shot fires at an angle of 45*(this is what I'm guessing the problem is because when the shooter is oriented at 45*, the shot is fired at exact 90*).

**Shooter angle(0,0,0)**

[image]

**Shooter angle(0,0,45)**

[image]

**Note- The ball always launches from the center of the black flattened cylinder object.**

Required Code:

```
public class ShotMoveScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public static float xForce;
    public Transform shott;
    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, 5f);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward, -5f);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            xForce += 0.2f;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            Instantiate(shott, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }

    }
}
```

Script attached to the ball which gets instantiated:

```
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour {
    void Update () {
        Rigidbody2D rb;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        rb.gravityScale = 0.8f;
        transform.Translate( new Vector3(1,1,0) * ShotMoveScript.xForce * Time.deltaTime, Space.Self);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post a sample of your code please?

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot, just a sec

Comment: The person who down voted this question, could you be kind enough to let  me know why did you do that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rotate the ball when instantiating it with the third parameter *rotation* (see [reference](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html)).
After that you apply a Vector pointing to (1, 1) so the ball will move along that direction **relative to his local rotation**.

Either pass [Quaternion.identity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html) as the third parameter to [Instantiate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) method or move the ball along (1, 0) direction.

Comment: Quaternion.identity didn't solve the problem at all. It now always shoots the ball at 45* angle no matter what the rotation angle of the shooter is.
Moving the ball along 1,0,0 didn't help either. But I almost got what I needed by moving it along 0,1,0. What happens now is at 0*, the ball shoots at 90* and at 270* the ball shoots at 0*.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal maybe you ran Unity before it recompiled and your latest changes. This happens sometimes.

Comment: Could be. I've seen Unity getting moody before.
Off topic, are you currently working with Unity?